# How to use filepaths with rename()?

Tags: c, rename

I use the rename() function, but it renames files only in the program directory. How can I point her to a file outside the program folder?

I tried to give an input string like
"/home/user/folder/file.txt"
"~/folder/file.txt"
But it still gave an error that the file was not found.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<errno.h>

int main(){
    char oldn[256]="~/testfolder/oldname.txt";
    char newn[256]="~/testfolder/newname.txt";
    int ret = rename(oldn, newn);

    if(ret!=0){
        fprintf(stderr, "Cant rename! Error: %d\n", errno);
        perror("error msg");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: `~` means a literal `~`. There's no interpolation in `rename`. If you want to get the user's home directory, there are no portable ways, but in Posix, `const char *home = getenv("HOME");` should do it.

Comment: `~/folder/file.txt` is not a valid path. In context of various shell interpreters `~` token is expanded to home folder location but this does not happen in C. Also note that target folder must already exist when invoking `rename`.

Comment: You could investigate the POSIX `wordexp()` function for expanding strings into words in a shell-like manner.

Answer (score 1):

Well getenv("HOME") Is working for me, and other paths like "home/user/folder/file.txt".

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).